# Getting error after complete the Commerce Site setup and try to reinstall the Package Storefront.Powered package)

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I try to setup Sitecore commerce 8.2.1 using the steps in document mentioned below

http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SitecoreCommerce/DeploymentGuide/en-us/index.html

When i complete the Commerce Site setup and try to reinstall the Package (Sitecore.Reference.Storefront.Powered.by.SitecoreCommerce.10.0.xxx.update package), I am getting the below error.

> Server Error in '/' Application The catalog set you specified does not
>   exist.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the
>   execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> Exception Details: CommerceServer.Core.EntityDoesNotExistException:
>   The catalog set you specified does not exist.
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

Answer (score 3):

The Initialize-CSSite step in *Set up a Commerce Server Site* should have installed the catalogs for you. Check the content editor here `/sitecore/Commerce/Catalog Management/Catalogs` to see if you have any catalogs. If you do, and none are selected, select one and save the item. If you don't have any catalogs, try re-importing:

```
Import-CSCatalog -Name MySiteName -File $catalogFile
```

Sitename should be CFSolutionStorefrontSite based on the install process and the catalog file should be located in `\Website\SitecoreCommerce\Data`

Details on individual Commerce Powershell CmdLets are [here](http://commercesdn.sitecore.net/SCpbCS82/SitecoreCommerceGettingStarted/en-us/#DeploymentGuide/c_PowerShellCmdLets.html).